# Opening Safari with URL from terminal also opens URL in default browser (Chrome)

Tags: terminal, safari, google-chrome, big-sur

My OS is Big Sur 11.1 and when I run the following in Terminal:

`/usr/bin/open -a /Applications/Safari.app https://www.google.com`

...Chrome, my default browser, opens first, quickly followed by Safari.

This appears to be new behavior in Big Sur; Catalina only opened Safari.

Am I missing something new in Big Sur that will prevent Chrome from opening?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this behavior has been fixed in 11.2

Comment: The behavior has returned in 11.2.3.